# Почему не работает встроенная функция .append()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list, append

Функция `.append()` не добавляет элемент в конец списка:

```
# Filter out Strings from an Array

# Create a function that takes a list of
# non-negative integers and strings and return a new list without the strings.
# Example: filter_list([1, "a", "b", 0, 15]) ➞ [1, 0, 15]


# 1.Тут я принимаю значение от пользователя
users_input = input().split()

# 1.1. В этот список я кидаю только числа
final_list = []

# 2. Эта функция перебирает список который ввёл пользователь
def int_or_string (users_var):

    # 3. Если значение в списке users_input == int, тогда кидаем его в final_list
    for i in users_var:
        if i == int:
            final_list.append(i)
        else:
            continue

# 4 Запускаем функцию и выводим final_list в консоль
int_or_string(users_input)
print (final_list)
```

Условия задачки, см. комментарии в коде.

Comment: `if type(i) == int:`..., а `else continue` убери, оно там не надо

Comment: в комментариях у вас пишет, что функция должна возвращать новый список, а вы этого не делаете. Как вариант переделать: `def int_or_string(users_var): return [i for i in users_var if type(i) == int]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в users_input после:

```
users_input = input().split()
```

все элементы - строки

```
>>> users_input
['1', 'a', 'b', '0', '15']
```

то к ним можно применить метод строк .isdigit():

```
def int_or_string (users_var):
    return [i for i in filter_list if i.isdigit()]
```

А если как в вашем примере (в функцию передается список разнотипных элементов):

```
filter_list([1, "a", "b", 0, 15])
```

то можно проверять type:

```
def filter_list(array):
    return [a for a in array if type(a)==int]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Я понял в чём причина.

Comment: @seledka, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)